# Why equations of motion doesn't work here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag

I've been trying to solve a dynamics problem

> A small projectile is fired vertically downward into a fluid medium with an initial velocity of 60 m/s due to the drag resistance of the fluid the projectile experiences a deceleration of $a =(-0.4 v^3) \frac{m}{s^2}$, where $v$ is in $\frac{m}{s}$. Determine the projectile's velocity and position $4s$ after it is fired

I thought it's logical to say 
$s = s_0 + v_0t + 0.5at^2
s = 0 + 0 + .5 (-0.4 v^3) (4^2)$
and for $v = v_0 - 1.6 v^3$
which wasn't the case but even after I saw the solution and got the value for the velocity from integration substituting in the first equation wasn't right, I've no idea why is it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$s=s_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2} a t^2$ is one of the equations of uniform acceleration. Since the acceleration depends on the velocity it isn't uniform so the equation of motion you attempted to use is invalid. The only way to treat this problem is by setting up and solving the differential equation $\frac{dv}{dt}=g-0.4v^3$, which is seperable so can be solved with relative ease.

Comment: I think you are missing a term in the differential equation.  Unless you have transformed g away.

Comment: @ggcg yeah my mistake, thank you

Comment: I got the point that acceleration is dependent on velocity so it's not uniform, but the in the book dv/dt = -0.4 v^3
and since it was asking when t is 4 so after the integration dv/-.4V^3 = dt
v was 0.559 m/s

Comment: @Abdelrahman Sherif I'm sorry but I'm not sure what that comment means

Comment: The problem statement gives the acceleration (not the friction). I would assume that already includes the effect of gravity.

Comment: @R.W. Bird it gives the deceleration due to drag, which I would assume means the drag force divided by the mass of the object

Comment: @AbdelrahmanSherif, I think to bemjanim's point, you need to derive the acceleration accounting for all forces from scratch.

Comment: I think if I've put the picture it would made it better but I couldn't sorry the fluid was water in the textbook I should have mention it, I think this is why the book solution didn't contain g in the solution